# Rust module import visibility in library crate

Tags: rust

It seems like I haven't fully understood Rust's module system yet. I have the following file structure:

```
module_issue
|_Cargo.toml
|_src
  |_main.rs
  |_lib.rs
  |_bindings
    |_mod.rs
```

This code compiles and runs without issues:

```
// file: bindings/mod.rs

pub fn say_hello() {
    println!("Hello from the bindings module!");
}
```

```
// file: lib.rs

mod bindings;

pub fn try_bindings() {
    bindings::say_hello();
}
```

```
// file: main.rs

use module_issue;

fn main() {
    module_issue::try_bindings();
}
```

However, if I make a sub-module in `lib.rs` and try to use `bindings::say_hello()` from there, I get a compiler error. Here's what `lib.rs` now looks like:

```
// file: lib.rs

mod bindings;

pub fn try_bindings() {
    bindings::say_hello();
}

mod debugging {
    pub fn try_bindings_debug() {
        bindings::say_hello(); // <- can't find 'bindings' - shouldn't it be in scope?
    }
}
```

and this is the error I get:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `bindings`
  --> src\lib.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         bindings::say_hello();
   |         ^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `bindings`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

In `lib.rs`, I also tried replacing `mod bindings;` with `use crate::bindings;`, but that resulted in a different error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::bindings`
 --> src\lib.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use crate::bindings;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `bindings` in the root

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `bindings`
  --> src\lib.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         bindings::say_hello();
   |         ^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `bindings`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

My understanding of the module system was as follows: If I bring a module `A` into the scope of module `B`, then the public members of `A` will be accessible in `B` and all the sub-modules of `B`. In this case, I bring the `bindings` module into the scope of the library root. The `debugging` module is a sub-module of that root, so it should have access to `bindings` as well. Can you tell me where I went wrong? My priority isn't really to solve the problem, but to understand why this doesn't work.

I'm working on Windows 10, with the following toolchain:

```
cargo 1.39.0 (1c6ec66d5 2019-09-30)
rustc 1.39.0 (4560ea788 2019-11-04)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I bring a module A into the scope of module B, then the public members of A will be accessible in B and all the sub-modules of B.

This assertion is incorrect. The scope of each module contains only things defined or used in the module itself, not in its parents.

You can, however, pull items from the parent explicitly:

```
mod debugging {
    use super::bindings; // referring to library root
    pub fn try_bindings_debug() {
        bindings::say_hello();
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f00b8f2ad8bd508012c34e96d565452)